# Second order non-homogeneous differential equation on particular solution form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got a question below with answer from the professor, although I think the answer may be wrong, but is there something I missed?

1. Determine the form of a particular solution to the ODE below. Do not solve for the coefficient.

$y'' + 4y' + 5y = e^{2t} + t^2 \sin(t) - e^{2t} \cos(t)$

I know the solution for the corresponding homogeneous equation is:
$r = -2 \pm i$

So the homogeneous solution has the following form:
$y_{h} = c_{1} e^{-2t}\cos(t) + c_{2}e^{-2t}\sin(t)$

For each term of the RHS, we can guess the following forms:
$e^{2t} \rightarrow Ae^{2t} $

$t^2\sin(t) \rightarrow (Bt^2 + Ct + d)\cos(t) + (Et^2 + Ft + G)\sin(t)$

$-e^{2t}\cos(t) \rightarrow He^{2t}\cos(t) + Ie^{2t}\cos(t)$

The the "guessed" form of the particular solution should be:

$Ae^{2t} + (Bt^2 + Ct + d)\cos(t) + (Et^2 + Ft + G)\sin(t) + He^{2t}\cos(t) + Ie^{2t}\sin(t)$

However, the professor's answer is:

$Ae^{2t} + (Bt^2 + Ct + d)\cos(t) + (Et^2 + Ft + G)\sin(t) + Hte^{2t}\cos(t) + Ite^{2t}\sin(t)$

The professor multiplied a $t$ in $Hte^{2t}\cos(t) + Ite^{2t}\sin(t)$

However, I do not see any of this in the solution of the homogeneous equation that there's a repetition that we need to multiply by $t$.

Could somebody help confirm the correct form of the particular solution?

Comment: Is your professor mentioning $Hte^{-2t}\cos t$ or $Hte^{2t}\cos t$? Is the original question stating $e^{-2t}\cos t$ instead?

Comment: I am sure the professor mentioned $Hte^{2t}\cos t$ and the original question states the RHS as $e^{2t}\cos t$

Comment: Could be there's a typo confusing $e^{2t}\cos t$ and $e^{-2t}\cos t$. But what must be wrong is that for both the $H$ and $I$ terms there is $\cos t$, when one of them should be $\sin t$.

Comment: sorry I corrected the typo. Assuming everything else is correct, for the H and I terms, should there be a multiplier t? thanks

Comment: You still have one place where $H$ and $I$ both have $\cos t$. And if there are no other typos, then, no, there shouldn't be a $t$ multiplier.